# how to group records in days based on timestamp value from current date in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I Have a table with a column as timestamp with timezone as shown below.

```
desc log_records:

id number not null,
event_id number not null,
event_desc varchar2(2000),
log_date timestamp with time zone
```

How do i suppose to group the records like

```
older than 300 days 12 rows
older than 250 days 12831 rows
older than 200 days 438121 rows
```

based on the  current date in oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Kaushik, thank you for sample data. (BTW, I think your solution is wrong, I'll leave a comment).*

I think that this is what you're looking for:

```
SQL> select
  2    sum(case when sysdate - trunc(log_date) > 300 then 1 else 0 end) "older than 300 days",
  3    sum(case when sysdate - trunc(log_date) > 250 then 1 else 0 end) "older than 250 days",
  4    sum(case when sysdate - trunc(log_date) > 200 then 1 else 0 end) "older than 200 days"
  5  from log_records;

older than 300 days older than 250 days older than 200 days
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
                  2                   3                   3

SQL>
```

Comment: You are welcome. I was in a hurry into something else stupid and hurriedly wrote the answer without giving a thought :-). I think your solution should logically be correct ( as it seems  from OP's row counts )

Comment: Don't worry, happens to me quite often :)

Comment: Thanks a ton @Littlefoot